# Consuming Zanox web service in a Django project

Tags: python, django, web-services, affiliate

I want to integrate Zanox feeds in a Django project. Unfortunately there seem to be no client library implementations in Python.

Or are there?

What is the next best alternative to a Python library? Using the Ruby version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would have been useful to say what Zanox was in your question. For those interested, they appear to be an advertising network.

Anyway, they do seem to expose a pretty simple XML or JSON feed, as [documented here](http://wiki.zanox.com/en/API_Most_Frequent_Use_Cases#How_do_I_get_results_in_JSON.3F). It looks pretty simple to get that using `urllib2` or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/index.html) and parse it using `json.load`.

Comment: They are very well known in Germany, so I guess my hope was for a German Python developer to have a pointer to an existing solution.

Comment: I will accept this answer, although I did it slightly differently (using httplib2 and eulxml).

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-zanox-api/ in a custom management command.